# Entity Framework connected records become null in a list

Tags: entity-framework-4

This is a tough one to describe.
I have a DB with table Tests and table students, and ScoreCards.
Each test has a FK of a student, same goes to scorecard.

Student can take the test more than once, so there can be many records of tests that points to the same student.

I currently use the scorecard only in memory.
I have a list of those scorecard objects: liScoreCard.
I iterate through all the tests, each iteration I create a new scorecard object, and finally - if it's the best - I add it to the list (if not, I just change the number of tests on the already existing score card in the list):

liScoreCards.Add(SC);

if the student has only one test, the SC in the list  contains the Student Object (when I get the list of test I use "Include("Student")" in the query.

if in a future test I find the same student again (in a later test)
when I do this:
(Adding the student object from the test to the new scorecard object)
sc.Student = test.Student

in the list: liScoreCards - the previous SC object.Student becomes NULL instead of the Student object that was there.

What am I doing wrong ?

Is it possible that assigning the student object to the new ScroeCard object "removes" it from the old scorecard object stored in the list ?

code sample:

```
 // Psuedo code:
 liTest = DB.GetTests().Include("Student");
 // Code: 
   List<ScoreCard> liScoreCard = new List<ScoreCard>();

    foreach(Test st in liTest)
    {
ScoreCard SC = new ScoreCard();
SC.Student = st.Student;        // This line makes SC with the same StudentID in liScoreCard have the Student become null.

ScoreCard oldSC = liScoreCard.Find(x->x.StudentID == SC.StudentID);
// Some logic to see which grade is higher)
// either update oldSC or...
liScoreCard.Add(SC);
}
```

}

Comment: I have a feeling I can do more for you if I see some code.

Comment: I will add some within 30 min.